# jquery menu widget open link from keypress

Tags: jquery, menu, widget, key

i have a jQuery-Menu widget and it works fine with accessibility.
but my problem is, i can't invoke a link from the menu with a keypress.
on http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/ there is a example, an this dont working to with keypress. no link will opened.
any ideas?

i tried:

```
$('a.ui-state-focus').bind('keyup', function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    console.log(keycode);
}
```

but it doesnt work

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? You might have to use `on()` and not `bind()`

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: i use jquery 1.9.1 with ui 1.10.3
i have used "on", too but no result.
on the official ui-demo page i cant open a link with any key, too.
http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/

Comment: here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G4mb3/
klick in the section where the menu is, press "Tab" and the focus is on the menuitem. now you can navigate with the cursorkeys but no key is given to go on that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a solution, but i dont know wether its the best:

```
$('#nav').menu({
    select: function(event, ui){
       window.location.href = $(ui.item).find('a.ui-state-focus:first').attr('href');
    }
});
```